Problemas de archivero
Intento hacer que en el programa se ejecute black o mismo pytest y me salta lo siguiente: La fórmula que utilicé en este caso es:
 El término 'pytest' no se reconoce como nombre de un 
cmdlet, función, archivo de script o programa ejecutable.
Compruebe si escribió correctamente el nombre o, si incluyó una     
ruta de acceso, compruebe que dicha ruta es correcta e inténtelo    
de nuevo.

La fórmula que utilicé en este caso es:
pytest calculator.py

Ya lo instalé varias veces y no me deja, probé con otra forma para ver si funcionaba y dice lo siguiente:
======================= test session starts =======================
platform win32 -- Python 3.12.4, pytest-8.2.2, pluggy-1.5.0
rootdir: C:\Users\maite
collected 0 items / 1 error

============================= ERRORS ============================== 
__________________ ERROR collecting test session __________________ 
<frozen genericpath>:112: in samefile
    ???
E   FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado: 'C:\\Users\\maite\\Mis documentos'
===================== short test summary info ===================== 
ERROR  - FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] El sistema no puede encontrar e...
!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 error during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!! 
======================== 1 error in 0.14s ========================= 

En este caso utilicé:
python -m pytest calculator.py


En el caso 2, tu problema puede ser que tienes dobles las barras invertidas, quizás por el uso de la r precediendo la cadena, o bien porque estás usando una ruta relativa que no existe en el script calculator.py. En el caso 1, el problema es que estás invocando a pytest desde la línea de comandos del sistema. Supongo que puedes utilizar ese comando desde el intérprete de Python interactivo.
